# merging 2 data frames and matching their values in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame called `df`

```
   Team      win    sum
0   1115    0.531    5
1   1124    0.774    5
2   1139    0.875    6
3   1140    0.848    4
4   1143    0.697    5
```

I have another data frame called `df1`

```
       season   seed    Team   seed_frequency
        2010    W01     1246     1
        2010    W02     1452     2
        2010    W03     1307     3
        2010    W04     1458     4
        2010    W05     1396     5
```

I need to form a new data frame so that the seed_frequency in `df1` matches the team names in `df`.

```
    Team     win    sum    seed_frequency
0   1115    0.531    5        7
1   1124    0.774    5        6
2   1139    0.875    6        4
3   1140    0.848    4        7 
4   1143    0.697    5        3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pd.merge

```
pd.merge(df,df1,on='Team',how='left')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html